# How to wait created variable to change before rendering data in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a variable that is called "name" inside my data(). And this is updated once I fetch this value from firebase using created() like this:

```js
created: async function fetchDataFromFirebase() {
        this.email = this.getCurrentUser().email
        await this.doctorsCollection.doc(this.email).get().then(async (doc) => {
            this.name = await doc.data().title + ' ' + await doc.data().firstName + ' ' + await doc.data().lastName
            this.speciality = await doc.data().speciality
            this.phone = await doc.data().phone
            this.profilePicture = doc.data().img == null || doc.data().img === '' ? 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/healthy-wo.appspot.com/o/doctors%2FMantraHW-T-Coral-01.png?alt=media&token=2ae855cb-c96d-4b97-b813-c844f9e0e871':doc.data().img
            // getCurrentAge will give the difference in years between today and the Date object you're passing
            this.age = this.getCurrentAge(new Date((await doc.data().birthDate).toMillis())) + ' años'

            // memberDate is a variable that holds the date this user was registered but in Date object format
            let memberDate = new Date((await doc.data().subscriptionStart).toMillis())
            this.member_duration = memberDate.getDate() + '/' + (memberDate.getMonth()+1<10 ? '0'+(memberDate.getMonth()+1):memberDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + memberDate.getFullYear()
        })
    },
```

My problem here though, is that I must wait for this variable to update and then asign it to a new variable inside data() too, called query. But everytime I reference it as this.name I get an error because name is undefined. Here's my query I'm trying to submit

```js
query: firebase.firestore().collection('feed').limit(3).where('author', '==', /*here goes name*/),
```

I must have this query variable in data() because then I got to pass it as a prop to a new component:

```html
<post-card
  v-bind:query="query"
></post-card>
```

Here's my data() too:

```js
data() {
        return {
            doctorsCollection: firebase.firestore().collection('doctors'),
            name: 'hello',
            query: firebase.firestore().collection('feed').limit(3).where('author', '==', this.name),
            speciality: '',
            member_duration: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            age: '',
            profilePicture: '',
            dialog: false
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved it by placing the query change inside created.

```js
created: async function fetchDataFromFirebase() {
        this.email = this.getCurrentUser().email
        await this.doctorsCollection.doc(this.email).get().then(async (doc) => {
            this.name = await doc.data().title + ' ' + await doc.data().firstName + ' ' + await doc.data().lastName
            this.speciality = await doc.data().speciality
            this.phone = await doc.data().phone
            this.profilePicture = doc.data().img == null || doc.data().img === '' ? 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/healthy-wo.appspot.com/o/doctors%2FMantraHW-T-Coral-01.png?alt=media&token=2ae855cb-c96d-4b97-b813-c844f9e0e871':doc.data().img
            // getCurrentAge will give the difference in years between today and the Date object you're passing
            this.age = this.getCurrentAge(new Date((await doc.data().birthDate).toMillis())) + ' años'

            // memberDate is a variable that holds the date this user was registered but in Date object format
            let memberDate = new Date((await doc.data().subscriptionStart).toMillis())
            this.member_duration = memberDate.getDate() + '/' + (memberDate.getMonth()+1<10 ? '0'+(memberDate.getMonth()+1):memberDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + memberDate.getFullYear()
        })
        this.query = firebase.firestore().collection('feed').limit(3).where('author','==', this.name.toString())
    },
    data() {
        return {
            doctorsCollection: firebase.firestore().collection('doctors'),
            name: 'hello',
            query: 'null',
            speciality: '',
            member_duration: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            age: '',
            profilePicture: '',
            dialog: false
        }
    },
```

And also using a v-if statement inside my component. So it won't be rendered unless query is different from an initial string.

```html
<post-card
    v-if="query !== 'null'"
    v-bind:query="query"
></post-card>
```